# Counting letter frequencies and print letter:count, but not duplicates in java strings

Tags: java, string, frequency, counting

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TextIO.putln("Text?");
    String line = TextIO.getln();
    line = line.toLowerCase();
    char[] arr = line.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++){
        if(Character.isLetter(arr[i])){
            int count;
            int j;
            for(j = 0,count = 0; j < line.length(); j++){;
                if( arr[i] == arr[j]){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            System.out.printf("%c:%d\n", arr[i],count);
        }

    }
}
```

If I enter the string josh it prints out
j:1
o:1
s:1
h:1
If I enter joshh it prints
j:1
o:1
s:1
h:2
h:2
but I want 
j:1
o:1
s:1
h:2

How do I, for any string with duplicates, only print out the unique letter and how many times it occurs total? I was thinking of maybe implementing a for loop that just checks for each letter and increment it such as
for ('a' : string)
    total++
and then increment the 'a' by one, so the next loop would check how many occurrences of b, then c, and so on.

Comment: You can add the characters you already printed out to a List and then check if each subsequent character is on the list using List.contains(char). If the List contains the char you skip the counting and go to the next char.

Answer (score 0):

How much java do you know? Is this an assignment? Have you been through data structures? Two options:

- Sort and then count
- Use a map (dictionary if you come from Python as your username suggests), increment in the first pass and then iterate over the keys to print the values

Comment: intro to cs class, definitely not data structures

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Map<Character, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (char c : line.toCharArray())
    if (Character.isLetter(c))
        map.compute(c, (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1);
for (Entry<Character, Integer> e : map.entrySet())
    System.out.printf("%c:%d\n", e.getKey(), e.getValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TextIO.putln("Text?");
    String line = TextIO.getln();
    line = line.toLowerCase();
    // char[] arr = line.toCharArray();
    Map<Character, Integer> occurrences=new LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++){
        int ch=line.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isLetter(ch)){
            if(occurrences.containsKey(ch)) {
              occurrences.put(ch, occurrences.get(ch)+1); // increment
            }
            else {
              occurrences.put(ch, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    for(char ch : occurrences.keySet()) {
      System.out.print(ch+":"+occurrences.get(ch)+";");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, it looks like the issue lies in the for loop you are using while printing.

What happens is that you evaluate for every single character in the string and print. Once you evaluate for the first h in josh, your program then moves on to the second h, evaluates again, and as a result, prints h and its count again.

You could try a data structure such as a dictionary which accounts for unique elements. Or, as you count how many times letters appear, you can have another array that holds letters already seen. If you check against this array before counting how many times a letter appears you can see if the letter has already been counted, if so you can just skip this character and move on to the next. It isnt the most elegant solution, but it would work